# New to SASS, SCSS with --webkit-scrollbar throws syntax error. Escape sequence?

Tags: sass

Hopeful to learn what one of these looks like in SCSS

```
div.navwrapper {
    position:relative;
    --webkit-scrollbar: 6px;
    background-color: transparent;      
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply omit the one `-` on your prefix(es).

```
div.navwrapper {
    -webkit-scrollbar: 6px;      
}
```

will work like a charm;)